# Google App Scripts: Parsing PDFs successful, but data in 'fillable fields' gets lost

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

I'm building a tool in Google App Scripts that compares an original pdf form (with blank fillable fields - no OCR should be necessary) to the completed field. Both documents are stored in the same google drive.

My general strategy is as follows:

1. Parse blank pdf form into an array of rows
2. Parse completed pdf form into an array of rows
3. Compare to find differences (the values that got filled in).

I'm using [mogsdad's Apps Script pdfToText utility](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/e6795e438615d252584f), which was successfully able to parse the blank form perfectly. The problem I've run into is that when I try to parse a completed form, all of the data in the fillable fields gets lost.

I've established that the loss of information happens at the following line in the code:

> var gdocFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, pdfFile, insertOpts);

When the pdf data is saved as a gdoc, any data in a fillable field goes missing.

I have established that if I open the pdf in DocHub or similar and save a copy (that is no longer editable), the data can be parsed.

My two plans of attack are either:

1. Find a way to parse a pdf with fillable forms, or
2. Find a way to 'flatten' the fillable forms out of a pdf so that it can be parsed (I'm not sure of the terminology around this).

Does anybody have any advice on where to look for a way to accomplish either option (or any other ideas)?

I feel like my problems with this are due to missing some knowledge about how PDFs work, rather than a javascript issue.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: There's no error. The text from the fields just isn't parsed into the gdoc.

Comment: As the current workaround (with V8 runtime), is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70970330