# Google Apps Script Not Reading editable fields on PDF

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a code on GoogleAppScript with ORC to get text from a PDF file on Google Drive, using the `getFileById()` but the problem is that this file is an Adobe PDF Forms type and the code reads only the texts that are not in the fields that were edited in the form. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get this?

The file that I used as an example: http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf **(Please, fill the file and save on your drive to test it)**

The PDF on my Drive:
[PDF file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1p8H.png)

This is the result:
[values ​​shown when code is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gA1c.png)

Here is my code:

```
function extractTextFromPDF() {

 var fileId = '[File ID here]';
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 //Get all PDF files:
 const fileID = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

 var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob()
 var resource = {
title: blob.getName(),
mimeType: blob.getContentType(),
};

// Enable the Advanced Drive API Service
var file = Drive.Files.insert( resource, blob, { ocr: true, ocrLanguage: 'en'  } ); 
//,supportsAllDrives: true

// Extract Text from PDF file
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
var text = doc.getBody().getText();

Logger.log(text)
return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from PDF form using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In order to test this situation, I used the following PDF file by inputting sample values. I obtained this PDF file from your question.

[image]

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) is used. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Apps Script, and set your file ID of the PDF file to `pdfFileId`.

```js
async function myFunction() {
  const pdfFileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of your PDF file on Google Drive.

  // Load pdf-lib
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText().replace(/setTimeout\(.*?,.*?(\d*?)\)/g, "Utilities.sleep($1);return t();"));

  const blob = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfFileId).getBlob();
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(new Uint8Array(blob.getBytes()));
  const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
  const { PDFTextField, PDFDropdown, PDFCheckBox, PDFRadioGroup } = PDFLib;
  const res = form.getFields().map(f => {
    const retObj = { name: f.getName() };
    if (f instanceof PDFTextField) {
      retObj.value = f.getText();
      retObj.type = "Textbox";
    } else if (f instanceof PDFDropdown) {
      retObj.value = f.getSelected();
      retObj.options = f.getOptions();
      retObj.type = "Dropdown";
    } else if (f instanceof PDFCheckBox) {
      retObj.value = f.isChecked();
      retObj.type = "Checkbox";
    } else if (f instanceof PDFRadioGroup) {
      retObj.value = f.getSelected();
      retObj.options = f.getOptions();
      retObj.type = "Radiobutton";
    } else {
      retObj.type = "Unknown";
    }
    return retObj;
  });
  console.log(res);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used in the above sample PDF file, the following value is obtained.

```json
[
  {"name":"Given Name Text Box","value":"test1","type":"Textbox"},
  {"name":"Family Name Text Box","value":"test2","type":"Textbox"},
  {"name":"House nr Text Box","value":"test4","type":"Textbox"},
  {"name":"Address 2 Text Box","value":"test5","type":"Textbox"},
  {"name":"Postcode Text Box","value":"test6","type":"Textbox"},
  {"name":"Country Combo Box","value":["Belgium"],"options":["Austria","Belgium","Britain","Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus","Czech-Republic","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Ireland","Italy","Latvia","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Netherlands","Poland","Portugal","Romania","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden"],"type":"Dropdown"},
  {"name":"Height Formatted Field","value":"1500","type":"Textbox"},
  {"name":"City Text Box","value":"test7","type":"Textbox"},
  {"name":"Driving License Check Box","value":true,"type":"Checkbox"},
  {"name":"Favourite Colour List Box","value":["Orange"],"options":["Black","Brown","Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Violet","Grey","White"],"type":"Dropdown"},
  {"name":"Language 1 Check Box","value":false,"type":"Checkbox"},
  {"name":"Language 2 Check Box","value":true,"type":"Checkbox"},
  {"name":"Language 3 Check Box","value":true,"type":"Checkbox"},
  {"name":"Language 4 Check Box","value":true,"type":"Checkbox"},
  {"name":"Language 5 Check Box","value":false,"type":"Checkbox"},
  {"name":"Gender List Box","value":["Man"],"options":["Man","Woman"],"type":"Dropdown"},
  {"name":"Address 1 Text Box","value":"test3","type":"Textbox"}
]
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the pdf-lib library is loaded in the script. But, of course, in this case, you can also use the pdf-lib library by copying and pasting the script library retrieved from `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js` in the script editor of Google Apps Script. In this case, the process cost for loading it can be reduced.

#### References:

- [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/)
- [Retrieving and Putting Values for PDF Forms using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/retrieving-and-putting-values-for-pdf-forms-using-google-apps-script-92412a7cf0af)

Answer (score 0):

The FDF data does not need to be stored in the order you see on the page, often may  be the order the fields were added. The easiest way to see the text /V(alues) in reply to /T(ext field) entries is via the FDF a user can save and send without the Source PDF. This has the added advantage that a CHECK box will be sent as **/V /Yes** or **/V /OFF** (= NOT checked) which is notoriously difficult with a binary PDF, however you need to know which text on the page was Language 1 since the author did not tag it as Deutsch!

What intrigues me most (without looking closer) is the count of attached objects only went up by 12 but there are more than that number of potentially added answers,
from a field :-) of 17.

```
/Lang(en-GB)
/AcroForm<</Fields[
5 0 R 7 0 R 8 0 R 9 0 R 10 0 R
11 0 R 12 0 R 13 0 R 14 0 R 16 0 R
17 0 R 18 0 R 19 0 R 20 0 R 21 0 R
22 0 R 23 0 R 
]/DR 37 0 R/NeedAppearances true>>
```

[image]

Anyway if you dont want to do it the easy way you will need to program something to read those object chains. Personally it takes each user a few seconds to export the forms or have them sent in the background by email however most modern users dont use historic mailto: so you have to get them to web mail the form for you to press the extract button.

So here is object 5 and we can see it is for your Given Name

```
5 0 obj
<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Widget/F 4
/Rect[165.7 453.7 315.7 467.9]
/FT/Tx
/P 1 0 R
/T(Given Name Text Box)
/TU<FEFF004600690072007300740020006E0061006D0065>
/V <FEFF>
/DV <FEFF>
/MaxLen 40
/DR<</Font 6 0 R>>
/DA(0 0 0 rg /F3 11 Tf)
/AP<<
/N 38 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
```

so the entry for `004600690072007300740020006E0061006D0065` converts to `First name` and we can see the answer when the user sends back the form as a PDF

```
5 0 obj
<</AP<</N 38 0 R >>/DA(0 0 0 rg /F3 11 Tf)/DR<</Font 6 0 R >>/DV<FEFF>/F 4/FT/Tx/MaxLen 40/P 1 0 R /Rect[ 165.7 453.7 315.7 467.9]/Subtype/Widget/T(Given Name Text Box)
/TU<FEFF004600690072007300740020006E0061006D0065>/Type/Annot/V(Brunno)>>
endobj
```